# How to stop for loop container to loop after data flow task is completed

Tags: for-loop, ssis

I have an SSIS Package that Picks up today's date.xlsx file from a particular folder. There are 1 million records in the sheet. The package is running and data is getting inserted into the Sql table but after all the records are processed the For loop container is continue to run and takes the same file again and again inserting the record. How am I supposed to stop the for loop to stop after data inserted and data flow task is completed?

Comment: Can you show the ForEach loop container configuration?

Comment: @Hadi The For each loop is basically having two variables one for the path and other for name of the file.I have a Excel file .xlsx format placed every day in one folder based on day-1 I have to pick up the file and place it into a Database table.I am able to run the package but once all 10lakhs records are processed it again takes the same file and inserts the same data which should not happen once it is successfully completed it should stop.Can i use a Variable as count and in the script task put it something like DTS.variable["user::count"].value=(int)Dts.Varibales["User::count"].Value+1;